# Where to create interface implementation?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, interface, solid-principles

I'm gonna ask perhaps simple an OO design question.

Imagine we inversed a dependency between two concrete classes ( Foo and Hoo ) using an interface (IHoo) where Hoo implements the interface and Foo uses that implementation.

At that point, I wondered where excatly I should attach that implementation ( Hoo ) to it's client ( Foo ). Obviously, if we add Hoo in the client class Foo, then we have not inversed the compile-time dependency ( with respect to runtime dependency ) and we have only made a bit more modular code, but not less-rigid.

So perhaps, we associate client and the interface implementation in a master ( or higher-level ) class like a controller or so? What's your approach would be ?

Thx.

Comment: The [metasyntactic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable) following _foo_ is typically _bar_.  ;)

Comment: As @samoht has answered, just pass Foo a reference to the IHoo instance that is created somewhere else. http://www.jamesshore.com/Blog/Dependency-Injection-Demystified.html

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Yes, got it :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the concept of a [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). This is where everything should be wired-up.

Factories can be used where the implementation is only known at run-time.

Comment: I'm going to look at it and return to you.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the other answers, and to get to the question of **Where to create interface implementation?** the [GRASP Creator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)#Creator) says (I've changed it for your context of Hoo):

> A class `B` should be responsible for creating instances of class `Hoo` if one or more of the following apply:
>
> - Instances of `B` contain or compositely aggregate instances of `Hoo`
> - Instances of `B` record instances of `Hoo`
> - Instances of `B` closely use instances of `Hoo`
> - Instances of `B` have the initializing information for instances of `Hoo` and pass it on creation.

David Osborne's answer points out (as does GRASP Creator) you can also use a Factory.